# What is a stop for RestFul Stateless API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda to host code which fetches data from dynamodb.

The request comes from a client and inturn, the lambda queries and gets the data and sends it back as response.

Does this serve as end of a transaction?

Do we also check about if the response we sent back is consumed or not by the requestor ? If yes, how to go about it in Lambda when its stateless. ( if we need to change the code, and add step function to lambda, i'm still confused if the requestor automatically will send a 200 OK or we should query ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Lambda returns the response and shuts down (this is good because you save money). If you are concerned about "exactly once delivery", consider using a message queue (eg: SQS, Kafka). Lambda will then publish to a topic and the requestor of data will subscribe to the topic.

Comment: Lambda doesn't 'shut down' and this question also doesn't relate at all to exactly once delivery. It is more related to synchronous/asynchronous invocation.

Comment: The instance of the Lambda does shut down and you eventually get a cold start. Not the best words but it is true. The post does not ask for message queue but instead asks for confirming if the message is consumed, message queue gives the guarantee that the message will be delivered and consumed, eventually. I think this solves the problem, unless you have another idea?

Comment: It doesn't immediately shutdown which is what your answer insinuates. There's nothing about a message in the question, and the mention of Step Functions in the question points me to thinking RE async/sync invocation. It solves the problem but only as well as getting a private jet to replace a 15 minute walk.

Comment: Yes thats right. @rkochar My case is that my lambda responds to someone's request. 
Now, wanted to know if in the same session, if Lambda could understand the response that we send got consumed or not based on 200 OK or 400 ? Is that even a possibility

Most likely i assume its not, but i did not understand how async flow will help here, Ermiya, can you explain a bit?

Comment: Also, after i send my message to a queue .. again what mechanism exists for the queue to know the message was successfully delivered? @rkochar

Comment: This depends on the queue you choose @Viv. [Exactly once delivery](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) guarantees that your message will be delivered to a subscriber. I recommend reading the documentation to learn more. To answer your question, On Kafka you can create another queue to acknowledge the message has been read or log it. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acknowledgements) has a different approach but it all depends on what you want to do and other constraints of your system.

Comment: Also, consider taking a look at transactions in Kafka. [1](https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kafka-transactions-and-guarantees/), [2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactional-systems-with-apache-kafka/), [3](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/). You can find several other examples, blogs and tutorials on various message queues.